# Passing [[xaxis,yaxis]] data to highchart series using jquery

Tags: highcharts

I need to pass data to Highchart series in the below format

```
series: [{ name: 'Deployment Latency', data: [[Date.UTC(2011, 6, 27, 01, 30), 6.76],
[Date.UTC(2011, 6, 27, 07, 30), 6.24],
[Date.UTC(2011, 6, 27, 13, 30), 6.45],
[Date.UTC(2011, 6, 27, 20, 30), 7.76],
[Date.UTC(2011, 6, 28, 01, 30), 6.76],
[Date.UTC(2011, 6, 28, 07, 30), 5.76],
[Date.UTC(2011, 6, 28, 13, 30), 6.20],
[Date.UTC(2011, 6, 28, 20, 30), 6.12],
[Date.UTC(2011, 6, 29, 01, 30), 6.41],
[Date.UTC(2011, 6, 29, 07, 30), 5.99],
[Date.UTC(2011, 6, 29, 13, 30), 6.25]]
```

How should i proceed to pass data using jquery.
xaxis is DataTime & y axis is double. Pls guide me

Comment: I'm sorry, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As the data you have is already an array of `Date` and `y` values, you should have no problems. [As stated in the documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#series--data), and in numerous other questions, highcharts can accept data in different formats.

In your case, you just need to pass it into the chart, as you would any other chart.

```
var your_data = {}; // assuming that the data you've listed is an object as described in your question.

chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'your_id'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    series: [{
        data: your_data.data
    }]
});
```